# If a sequence of random variables is uniformly bounded, is it's limit bounded as well?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose that I have a sequence of uniformly bounded random variables $X_n$ and that I know that:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = X
$$

Is it true that $X$ is uniformly bounded as well? Here I define uniformly bounded to be that $X$ has an upper and lower bound. I am able to show that if a function $f$ is uniformly bounded, then its limit at any point is bounded as well. However, I understand that random variables may be viewed as a sequence of functions, but I don't know how to generalize my result from a single function to a sequence of functions. Would anyone have any hints? Thanks!

Comment: By "uniformly bounded" do you mean there exists $M$ such that $\mathbb P(|X_n|>M)=0$ for all $n$?

Comment: And in what sense do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n=X$? There are many forms of convergence of random variables.

Comment: @Math1000 If none is specified, how does that not mean sure convergence?

Comment: If by "sure convergence" you mean pointwise convergence in the classic analytical sense $$|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0,$$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$ that almost surely is not what @user136503 means :)

Comment: @Math1000 Lol okay. Is that because of uniform something?

Comment: Actually, I suppose "uniformly bounded" would mean that there exists $M>0$ such that $\sup_n|X_n|\leqslant M$ a.s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ is uniformly bounded, i.e. there exists $M>0$ such that $\sup_n|X_n|\leqslant M$ a.s., and that $X_n\stackrel{\mathrm{a.s.}}\longrightarrow X$. Then we may choose $N$ such that $n\geqslant N$ implies $|X_n-X|<1$ a.s. Hence with probability $1$,
$$|X| = |X-X_N+X_N| \leqslant |X-X_N|+|X_N|\leqslant M+1, $$
so that $X$ is bounded.